# Пунктуация в предложениях с междометиями

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли еще знаки препинания в данных примерах? И есть ли лишние?

1. Ух! ты какая!
2. Ух! ты, какая красота!
3. Семен Семеныч шел-шел, и тут - бабах - и поскользнулся на арбузной корке.
4. Целился-целился, прицелился: бац, бац... и мимо.
5. Стояли, разговаривали, и тут она ни с того ни с сего - хрясь - и влепила ему пощечину.

Answer (score 4):

Ух ты какая!

Ух ты, какая красота!

Семен Семеныч шел-шел, и тут - бабах! - и поскользнулся на арбузной корке.

Целился-целился, прицелился: бац-бац!... и мимо.

Стояли, разговаривали, и тут она ни с того ни с сего - хрясь! - и влепила ему пощечину.

Comment: Не могу понять, почему запятая нужна перед "и тут" в 3-м предложении.

Answer (score 3):

Вспомним классику (оформление похожей лексики):

«Правая нога — хрусть, пополам! Левая — хрусть, пополам! Вот до чего эти трамваи доводят!».. Но Коровьев до того разрыдался, что ничего нельзя было понять кроме повторяющихся слов «хрусть – и пополам!».